# Inexperienced programmer requesting assistance in finding the error in a Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google Sheets tells me that there is a formula parse error for the following and I can't seem to find my mistake.

I have little programming experience but I want to make a fairly simple invoice form for the business I work in. I've written the following formula in a line total:

```
=IF(B28="Rabais", if(REGEXMATCH(I28,%),((sum(J19:J27)*I28)*-1), (I28*-1)), if(H28=0, I28, (H28*I28)))
```

I need that line total to change according to the following rules:

If the value "Rabais" is selected in the dropdown in cell B28, and if cell I28 contains a percentage, then the formula returns the negative of that percentage of the sum of the values of cells J19 to J27.

If the first criteria is true and the value of I28 isn't a percentage, then the formula returns the negative of the value of I28.

If  the first criteria is false, then the formula checks if H28 is empty, and if so it returns the value of I28

If both If statements return false, then the formula returns the value of H28 times the value of I28.

I thought I had written everything properly, but obviously, I made a mistake somewhere and I can't seem to find it so I would appreciate a fresh set of eyes pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do it:

```
=IF(B28="Rabais", 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(I28), "%"), (SUM(J19:J27)*I28)*-1, I28*-1),
 IF(H28=0, I28, H28*I28))
```